# Can a stress-energy tensor induce signature changes on the metric?

Tags: general-relativity, metric-tensor, stress-energy-momentum-tensor, wick-rotation

Suppose we use the signature of a Riemannian manifold

$$
\eta^{\mu\nu}=\operatorname{diag}(+,+,+,+)
$$

as the starting point to describe a 4d Euclidean version of general relativity. Alternatively one may use a Wick rotation on time $t\to i \tau$ on normal general relativity to get this metric.

But instead of remaining in Euclidean GR, one then further flips the metric back to Lorentz $\eta^{\mu\nu}=\operatorname{diag}(+,-,-,-)$ but this time using the Stress-Energy tensor, instead of a wick rotation.

One will end up with the correct Lorentz signature $\eta^{\mu\nu}=\operatorname{diag}(+,-,-,-)$ but also with a non-zero stress-energy tensor.

My question is; what is the simplest stress-energy tensor which curves a $(+,+,+,+)$ flat metric into one with curvature $(+,-,-,-)$?

Comment: There is no mechanism for a signature change in GR. I'm not sure if this has been studied in mathematics but there is no mechanism for it in physics.

Comment: What do you mean by "flips the metric back to Lorentz using the Stress-Energy tensor"?

Comment: @J.Murray Well the stress-energy tensor is correlated to the metric of space-time, right? For example, if you place a lot of matter/energy in a small volume you get a black hole (Schwarzschild metric), etc. My question is; does there exist a stress-energy tensor such that a (+,+,+,+) metric is "curved" to a (+,-,-,-) metric? In that case, the Pseudo-Riemannian feature of the otherwise Riemannian metric is induced by the distribution of matter and energy in the system, rather than by postulating the metric to be Pseudo-Riemannian. I hope this is clearer...

Comment: @J.Murray Instead of placing a lot of matter/energy in a small volume to get the Schwarzschild metric, you would distribute matter/energy appropriately in all of the space-time such that you get a parity inversion from (+,+,+,+) to (+,-,-,-).

Comment: @JohnRennie Well, in my question I ask for a parity change with does not change the full signature, but only flips the sign of the space elements. Does your statement also applies to parity inversion or just signature changes? A signature change would be (-,+,+,+) to (+,-,-,-) and an example of a parity inversion would be (+,+,+,+) to (+,-,-,-).

Comment: That's a very interesting question. As a first step one may ask what happens to the Einstein tensor in a neighbourhood in which the metric tensor changes signature – and hence must be degenerate at some points. Unfortunately I don't know the answer, but now I'm very curious too.

Comment: Note that it *may* happen that no stress-energy-momentum tensor can achieve that: from the point of view of a 3+1 initial-value problem, it may happen that the set of evolution equations becomes singular and hence there's no continuation of the solution. As I already said I'm curious too.

Comment: @AlexandreH.Tremblay Parity inversion takes $\vec r \rightarrow -\vec r$; you are proposing taking $d\vec r^2 \rightarrow -d\vec r^2$, which is a very different thing.

Comment: @J.Murray noted. So like a "Wick rotation" of the space variables.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the standard formulation of GR, this is not possible.  This is because the metric tensor field is assumed to be everywhere non-degenerate and continuous, and in order to pass from a region of signature (++++) to a region of signature (+---), you need to pass through some regions at which the metric is either degenerate or discontinuous.

As a toy model, one could imagine a metric tensor field of the form
$$ds^2 = dt^2+x (dx^2+dy^2+dz^2)$$

which would have signature (++++) for $x\gt 0$ and $(+---)$ for $x\lt 0$. However, on the hyperplane $x=0$, the metric would have signature $(+000)$ and would therefore be degenerate.

These assumptions are baked into Einstein's equations.  Recall that

$$\Gamma^i_{\ \ j k}= \frac{1}{2} g^{i\alpha}(\partial_j g_{\alpha k} + \partial _k g_{\alpha j} - \partial_\alpha g_{jk})$$

and
$$R = g^{\alpha \beta}R_{\alpha \beta}$$

If the metric is not at least continuous, then the $\Gamma$'s are not well-defined (or involve things like delta functions) at the points of metric discontinuity.  Furthermore, the components of the inverse metric are the matrix inverse of the components of the metric; if the metric is degenerate, then it is non-invertible, so the "inverse metric" doesn't exist.  The entire structure of raising and lowering indices (or at least raising them) depends on the non-degeneracy of the metric, so we must abandon it if we wish to allow metrics with spatially varying signatures.

---

That being said, apparently the idea of spacetimes which contain multiple regions of different metric signature has been kicked around for a while.  A quick search of the arXiv yields [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/9610063), and the subsequent [23 papers which have cited it](https://inspirehep.net/literature?sort=mostrecent&size=25&page=1&q=refersto%3Arecid%3A425119) which you might find interesting. I am nowhere close to an expert on even *standard* GR, much less fairly dramatic extensions of it, so this is where my ability to speak coherently on the topic ends.

Comment: Hello, I was more thinking of a case where, using your "toy" metric, $x=-1$. Thus, $x$ would not change. The metric would be $(+,-,-,-)$ everywhere and thus "unique". Is there a stress-energy tensor that can fix $x$ to $-1$ for metric initially defined as $(+,+,+,+)$? If I then define this stress-energy tensor as the "true vacua of space" then I do not need to worry about the possibility of my metric switching to a different signature.  Does a stress-energy tensor that fixes $x$ to $-1$ change anything to your conclusion? In this case there would be no discontinuity nor degeneracy.

Comment: @AlexandreH.Tremblay I don't understand what you mean when you say a metric *initially* has signature (++++) but also has signature (+---) *everywhere*.  Everywhere means everywhere in *spacetime* - at all points, and at all times.

Comment: I apologize if I am using the wrong terms. My understanding of General Relativity is that it recovers Special Relativity in the absence of matter/energy; that is when the stress-energy tensor is zero everywhere. Now imagine instead that we define an analog to General Relativity, called Euclidean gravity, that instead recovers a metric with signature (+,+,+,+) when the stress-energy tensor is zero. Now I ask, in Euclidean gravity, what is the stress-energy tensor whose corresponding metric is (+,-,-,-) everywhere? In this case, there is no change of metric signature in spacetime.

Comment: @AlexandreH.Tremblay [Let's continue this in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/110234/discussion-between-j-murray-and-alexandre-tremblay).